# Can values be added to Sum_Range in a SUMIF formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to calculate weighted GPA in Excel. Unweighted was a simple average formula, but weighted is more complicated because a simple average cannot be taken. A weighted class is indicated by the presence of "AP" in a certain cell, and a non-weighted class is indicated by the presence of "Reg". To calculate weighted GPA, I need to take the component of non-weighted classes and weighted classes separately and then add them together.

For example, I can use this to calculate the non-weighted component: `((SUMIF(H4,"<>AP",G4))+(SUMIF(J4,"<>AP",I4))+(SUMIF(L4,"<>AP",K4))+(SUMIF(N4,"<>AP",M4))+(SUMIF(P4,"<>AP",O4))+(SUMIF(R4,"<>AP",Q4))+(SUMIF(T4,"<>AP",S4))+(SUMIF(V4,"<>AP",U4))+(SUMIF(X4,"<>AP",W4))+(SUMIF(Z4,"<>AP",Y4))+(SUMIF(AB4,"<>AP",AA4))+(SUMIF(AD4,"<>AP",AC4)))` divided by `(COUNTIF(G4:AD4,"Reg"))`.

I have to have each cell added manually in Excel because it will not do it for me. But each sum looks like this:

```
((SUMIF(H4,"<>AP",G4))
```

I could have used "Reg" but I used "<>AP" and that seems to be working. I didn't start using "Reg" until after I wrote this part of the formula. I could use "<>AP" or "Reg" - it doesn't matter.

I would think that I could modify the sum for the weighted component to this:

```
((SUMIF(H4,"AP",(G4+1)))
```

But Excel does not let me do this. I need to add 1 to G4, because a weighted class is worth 1 GPA point more, and I need it inside the parentheses because it should only be added if the SUMIF is true. But Excel does not let me do this; it thinks I am keying in something besides a formula and the formula becomes invalid.

In other words, the cells to sum contain unweighted GPA, and I need to add 1 to all of the cells that do get summed to get weighted GPA, but Excel is not letting me do this.

I have also tried: `((SUMIF(H4,"AP",G4+1))`

Nothing is working.

How can I add a number, in this case 1, to the value of a cell in a SUMIF that should be added if the criteria is true? I want to take the value in that cell (G4) and add a number to it in my formula.

Is this possible to do in a formula, or does the value "1" need to be explicitly defined in a cell, and then a reference to the cell containing it be made in the formula itself? (which would be really dumb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this a different way.

Instead of adding 1 to each weighted class individually, you can just add the COUNT of weighted classes to the sum of SUMIFs.

The complete formula to calculate weighted GPA is below:

```
(
((SUMIF(H4,"<>AP",G4))+(SUMIF(J4,"<>AP",I4))+(SUMIF(L4,"<>AP",K4))+(SUMIF(N4,"<>AP",M4))+(SUMIF(P4,"<>AP",O4))+(SUMIF(R4,"<>AP",Q4))+(SUMIF(T4,"<>AP",S4))+(SUMIF(V4,"<>AP",U4))+(SUMIF(X4,"<>AP",W4))+(SUMIF(Z4,"<>AP",Y4))+(SUMIF(AB4,"<>AP",AA4))+(SUMIF(AD4,"<>AP",AC4)))
+
(((SUMIF(H4,"AP",(G4)))+(SUMIF(J4,"AP",(I4)))+(SUMIF(L4,"AP",(K4)))+(SUMIF(N4,"AP",(M4)))+(SUMIF(P4,"AP",(O4)))+(SUMIF(R4,"AP",(Q4)))+(SUMIF(T4,"AP",(S4)))+(SUMIF(V4,"AP",(U4)))+(SUMIF(X4,"AP",(W4)))+(SUMIF(Z4,"AP",(Y4)))+(SUMIF(AB4,"AP",(AA4)))+(SUMIF(AD4,"AP",(AC4))))+(COUNTIF(G4:AD4,"AP")))
)
/(COUNT(G4:AD4))
```

The first line is the unweighted component.

The second line is the weighted component. Notice the COUNTIF at the end that solved the problem.

The third line divides by the number of grades.